# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object error al momento de sacar nombre id de relacion uno a muchos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo ese error al querer hacer una relación uno a muchos de la tabla libros y users mediante su respecto id pero me sale este error,como lo soluciono?[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWxfo.png)
Ya probe varias cosas y no se porque el id de user que es una llave foranea sigue como valor null

```
//modelo libro
    <?php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Libro extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $fillable = ['Nombre','user_id','Editorial','Categoria','Isbn','Paginas','Encuadernacion','Tipo','Foto'];
        //protected $guarded =['id'];
        public $timestamps =false;
        public function user(){
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
            
        }
    }
   // modelo user
    <?php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
        ];
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast.
         *
         * @var array<string, string>
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
        public function libros(){
            return $this->hasMany(Libro::class);
            
        }
    }
    //tabla users
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        }
    }
    //tabla libros
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    class CreateLibrosTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('libros', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string("Nombre");
                $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->string("Autor");
                $table->string("Editorial");
                $table->string("Categoria");
                $table->string("Isbn");
                $table->string("Paginas");
                $table->string("Encuadernacion");
                $table->string("Tipo");
                $table->string("Foto");
                
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('libros');
        }
    }
    //index
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
    @if(Session::has('mensaje'))
    {{Session::get('mensaje') }}
    @endif
    <br>
    <a href="{{url('libro/create')}}" class="btn btn-success"> Registrar Nuevo Libro </a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-light">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Editorial</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Isbn</th>
                <th>Paginas</th>
                <th>Encuadernacion</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            @foreach($libros as $libro)
            <tr>
                
                <td>{{$libro->id}}</td>
                
                
                <td>
                    
                <img src = "{{ asset('storage').'/'.$libro->Foto }}" width = "200" alt="">
                    
                </td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->user_id->name}}</td>//aquí es donde no me deja sacar el name del usuario y por ende me tira el error
                <td>{{ $libro->Autor}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Editorial}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Categoria}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Isbn}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Paginas}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Encuadernacion}}</td>
                <td>{{ $libro->Tipo}}</td>
                <td>
                    
                <a href = "{{ url ('/libro/'.$libro->id.'/edit')  }}" class = "btn btn-warning">
                    Edit
                </a>
                  
                <form action = "{{ url('/libro/'.$libro->id) }}" class = "d-inline" method = "post">
                @csrf
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                <input class= "btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick ="return confirm('¿Quiéres borrar?')" value="Borrar">
                
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: En `Libro`, el método que te retorna la instancia de `User` ha sido definido así: **`public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }`**, entonces, en el `td`, la llamada debería ser así: **`$libro->user->name`**

Answer (score 0):

En `Libro`, el método que define tu propiedad de relación dinámica es este:

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);            
    }
```

Entonces, tienes que usar ese método para acceder a los datos de `User`, pero tú lo estás buscando en `user_id`:

```
    <td>{{ $libro->user->name}}</td>//aquí es donde no me deja sacar el name del usuario y por ende me tira el error
```

Para más detalles [revisa la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) y los ejemplos de código que hay en ella.